# ASF file can't be rendered by GraphEdit but can be played by WMP

Tags: directshow, asf, windows-media-encoder

My program uses Windows Media Foundation WMV/WMA MFTs to encode to ASF format (mux is done by ffmpeg). Generated file can be played perfectly by Windows Media Player on Win10 but failed to be rendered by GraphEdit, error code == NS_E_INVALID_DATA (0xC00D002FL).

Same error happens when IWMSyncReader->GetNextSample is used to read audio sample.

A sample broken video is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/x8uyaqbclq93u5d/big_buck_bunny.wmv?dl=0

Could anyone take a look to check the cause?
Thanks

Comment: The broken video doesn't contain Extended Stream Properties objects for video and audio. You can examine it with a tool like MS Windows Media ASF Viewer: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12826. It seems that you need to configure the ASF media sink properly in order to make it create the Extended stream properties.

Comment: By the way, I used the SimplePlay sample program on Win7 and Win10, the video can be played on both platform perfectly.

Could it caused by some limitation of Windows Media API?

Comment: It can also play perfectly in WMP on both Win7 and Win10. Only the Windows Media API fails to read audio.

Answer (score 0):

After examining your wmv file with Windows Media ASF Viewer, I came to the conclusion that it was encoded by Lavf encoder (FFMPEG). Therefore, I installed [LAV directshow filters](https://github.com/Nevcairiel/LAVFilters/releases) and played the wmv with [Graphstudionext](https://www.videohelp.com/software/GraphStudio). I added the file as a File source async and after that the graph automatically used the LAV splitter. It seems that only LAV splitter is able to parse this wmv. In your app you can do the same by adding the file via the [File source async filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375641(v=vs.85).aspx) and let LAV parse it (if installed).